# I want my code to keep adding new elements to my list as the user types them one by one. But the code does not do it

Tags: python, list, input, append, element

Here is my code. I want it to keep adding elements to the list as the user types them.

```
**while True:
    _list = []
    new_element = input('typehere:')
    _list.append(new_element)
    print(_list)**
```

Here is the output :

```
typehere:**element_1**
['element_1']
typehere:**element_2**
['element_2']
```

I want:

```
typehere:element_1
['element_1']
typehere:element_2
[ 'element_1' , 'element_2' ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the `list` outside the loop:

```
_list = []

while True:
    new_element = input('typehere:')
    _list.append(new_element)
    print(_list)
```

Output:

```
typehere:>? element_1
['element_1']
typehere:>? element_2
['element_1', 'element_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Never mind... I get it now... every time the loop restarts the variable does not save the previous values because I have declared it as an empty list. This code works:

```
liist = []
while True:
    new_element = input('Type here :')
    liist.append(new_element)
    print(liist)
```

Comment: Haha. Thank you Sushil.